# ContextMenu with CompositeCollection in TreeView: Menu items disappear

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TreeView which is going to contain many different kinds of tree nodes with context menus. The context menus for the different types of tree nodes will be different, but will also share some sections. I only want to define the common menu sections once. I therefore define some common arrays of menu items as a resource, and then pull them into each context menu using a CompositeCollection. A very simple example of my scenario is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewCompositeContextMenuProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewCompositeContextMenuProblem"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="EditMenuItems" Type="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" />
            <MenuItem Header="Paste" />
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" />
        </x:Array>
        <x:Array x:Key="CommonMenuItems" Type="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <MenuItem Header="View properties" />
        </x:Array>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource EditMenuItems}" />
                                <Separator />
                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource CommonMenuItems}" />
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="treeView">
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

where the ItemViewModel is simply defined as

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Children {get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public ItemViewModel(string name)
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I then bind the treeView as follows:

```
var vm = new ItemViewModel("root");
var a = new ItemViewModel("a");
var b = new ItemViewModel("b");
var c = new ItemViewModel("c");
vm.Children.Add(a);
vm.Children.Add(b);
b.Children.Add(c);
treeView.ItemsSource = new List<ItemViewModel>() { vm };
```

Now, if, when running the application, I open the context menu on item "a", then on item "b" and then on item "a" again, I get the following result:

[image: bug]

I guess my use of CompositeCollection introduces some kind of sharing which does not play well with data templates. Does anyone know what goes wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context menus are managed better if they are **shared** among contexual visuals provided that their underlying items source is shared list of menu items (like your case). So basically in your case the context menu should be declared as a static resource and then shared between all text blocks individually.

```
  <Window.Resources>
     ....
     <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
          <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
             <CompositeCollection>
               <CollectionContainer
                   Collection="{StaticResource EditMenuItems}" />
               <Separator />
               <CollectionContainer
                   Collection="{StaticResource CommonMenuItems}" />
               </CompositeCollection>
          </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
    </ContextMenu>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                  ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}">
       ....
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>  
  </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: That's a good point - thanks. However, there will still be problems if multiple context menus are using the "EditMenuItems" collections, since this will introduce sharing of the individual menu items across menus. I found that adding x:Shared="False" to the x:Array elements helped. This instructs the XAML parser to copy the arrays verbatim instead of referencing them.

Comment: @UlrikRasmussen: this fixed the problem for me.